# Uncaught Error: Cannot call `compile` without the template compiler loaded. Please load `ember-template-compiler.js` prior to calling `compile`

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

im new to the ember.js framework and using ruby on rails and ember.debug.js -v 1.10.1(latest release). I have been reading online that ember changed this latest patch but i cant figure out how to fix my problem of:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot call `compile` without the template compiler loaded. Please load `ember-template-compiler.js` prior to calling `compile`.
```

Could someone please nudge me in the direction to getting my compiler to run properly? i wish i knew what code snippets from my project would help determine the answer...

Comment: ember.debug-f7fe3e766d5d5a45e5c3c26796439ed8.js?body=1:3976 DEBUG: Ember  : 1.10.0
ember.debug-f7fe3e766d5d5a45e5c3c26796439ed8.js?body=1:3976 DEBUG: jQuery : 1.11.2
ember.debug-f7fe3e766d5d5a45e5c3c26796439ed8.js?body=1:3976 DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.debug-f7fe3e766d5d5a45e5c3c26796439ed8.js?body=1:36836 Uncaught Error: Cannot call `compile` without the template compiler loaded. Please load `ember-template-compiler.js` prior to calling `compile`.

Answer (score 2):

This post may help you:

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html

If you're not using ember-cli - your HTML should look something like this:

```
<script src="assets/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
<script src="assets/ember.debug.js"></script>
```

If you are using ember-cli your templates should be precompiled and you shouldn't be having that problem.

Answer (score 1):

We need to include the ember-template-compiler.js in our application. I think ember-rails does not include this by default.

Add this in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

`//= require ember-template-compiler`