# Compile templates in the browser

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a specific use-case where I need to compile a template in the browser. That is because the template is not available at development-time.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const myTempRouteList = ['home']; // this is retrieved from the backend

export function initialize(instance) {
  let container = instance.container;
  let Router = container.lookupFactory('router:main');

  myTempRouteList.forEach(function (name) {
    let routeName = name.dasherize();

    Router.map(function(){ // router.map is undefined here
      this.resource(routeName, {path: routeName});
    });
    container.register(`route:${routeName}`, Ember.Route.extend({}));
    container.register(`template:${routeName}`, Ember.HTMLBars.compile(`I am the template of ${routeName}`);

  }, this);
}

export default {
  name: 'register-routes',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

I run it and it is giving the following error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot call 'compile' without the template compiler loaded. Please load 'ember-template-compiler.js' prior to calling 'compile'`.

So I added this to my Brocfile.js:

```
app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

However, the error is still present.

**Edit 2015-07-29**
When I hack the ember-template-compiler into the app\index.html file it works:

```
<body>
  {{content-for 'body'}}

  <script src="//builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.5/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
  ....
```

The versions I use:

- Ember 1.13.5
- Ember-cli 1.13.1

Comment: Possible duplicate issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843787/uncaught-error-cannot-call-compile-without-the-template-compiler-loaded-plea

Comment: Do you have an entry for `ember-template-compiler` in your `bower.json`?

Comment: @dhaulagiri The matching ember-template-compiler is included in the ember package.  Could you paste the line I should add to my `bower.json`?

Comment: `"ember-template-compiler": "http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.3/ember-template-compiler.js"`

Comment: @dhaulagiri that is not helping. I edited the question with more information.

Comment: In ember-cli 1.13, Brocfile.js was replaced by ember-cli-build.js

Comment: @gaurav You helped me a lot! I did miss that, I was able to solve the issue. Will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. There were 2 things:

1. I missed the renaming of `Brocfile.js` to `ember-cli-build.js`. I fixed that by following the [Transition Guide](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)
2. I needed to prepend the `ember-template-compiler` to my build by passing `{ prepend: true }` to my import statement:

   `app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js', { prepend: true });`

I also removed the `bower.json` line which loaded `ember-template-compiler` because it was not necessary, `ember-template-compiler` is included in the bower ember package.

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize that this was shipped with the ember package now